# How to deploy online cinema ticketing system

Tags: sql-server, system, analysis

If let's say a cinema company wants to install online cinema ticketing system which allows users to book movies tickets online, may I know that what will be the best installation strategy?

Before this online system, the customers have to go to the cinemas and buy the tickets at the counters.

During the installation process, how to make sure once a seat is booked online, the counters at the cinema branches will also shows that the seat is being booked?

Here's the options of installation strategy:

**a. Direct Installation**
- Changing over from the old system to a new one by turning off the old system when the new system is turned on.

**b. Parallel Installation**
- running the old information system and the new one at the same time until management decides the old system can be turned off.

**c. Single-location installation**
- trying out an information system at one site and using the experience to decide if and how the new system should be deployed throughout the organization/

**d. Phased Installation**
- changing from the okd information system to the new one incrementally, starting with one or a few functional components and then gradually extending the installation to cover the whole new system.

According to your opinions, which method is the best in according to the case above? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Direct Installation.  You do not want the problem of merging data from two different systems.  Also, you have all the time in the world to set up and test the new system while the old is still running.  You should know very well how to use the new system once you go live.  The key is proper testing.

The question, though, is a bit vague and I am not sure that it is truly a programming question that belongs on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that Direct Installation wouldn't be the best way to switch, because people would still end up turning up at the Cinema wanting to buy tickets.

In my opinion, I think that Parallel Installation would be a good choice because it would allow people to get used to the new system and settle into using it before you stopped using the old one, but you could use b, c or d.